# How to check if a unicode character is within given range in C?

Tags: c, utf-8, c++builder

The following function was written for java and has been adapted for C.

```
bool isFullwidthKatakana(WideChar C)
{
  return(('\u30a0'<=C)&&(C<='\u30ff'));
}
```

The problem is that my framework ("CodeGear C++Builder") shows this error:

> [BCC32 Warning] Unit1.cpp(101): W8114
>   Character represented by
>   universal-character-name '\u30a0'
>   cannot be represented in the current
>   code page (1252)

and it does not return true whether the conditions are met.

For example one input is 'ア' (0x30A2).

What should I do? How can I change the code page?

**Thank you to the three answers they all resolved it.**

```
return((0x30a0<=C)&&(C<=0x30ff));
```

It seems the that the expression \u30a0 wasn't correct, this all were correct

```
return((0x30a0<=C)&&(C<=0x30ff));
return (unsigned int) C >= 0x30a0u && (unsigned int) C <= 0x30ffu;
return((L'\u30a0'<=C)&&(C<=L'\u30ff'));
```

Comment: Suggestion: modify the title, since you are not asking how to check if a code point is valid (UTF-8 can encode *all* valid Unicode codepoints).

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using?

Comment: CodeGear C++Builder 2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to cast (explicitly or implicitly) the character to an unsigned integer, and then just use such constants:

```
return (unsigned int) C >= 0x30a0u && (unsigned int) C <= 0x30ffu;
```

should do it.

By the way, I'd recommend against using a (single-character) uppercase argument name, it's very easy to think it's a compile-time constant (which are typically uppercase in C and C++).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to check if a wide unicode character (probably utf-16 since you're on Windows) is within a range. This can be done with the code you've shown, you just have to make the character literals wide character literals. In C++ and C, they are made by prepending L to the literal, eg. `L'a'` or `L"ahoj"`.

In your case, I'd try

```
bool isFullwidthKatakana(WideChar C)
{
  return((L'\u30a0'<=C)&&(C<=L'\u30ff'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be related to the use of the character literal, not the test. So test against the codepoint as an integral literal, eg:

```
bool isFullwidthKatakana(WideChar C)
{
  return(( (WideChar)0x30a0 <= C )&&(C <= (WideChar)0x30ff ));
}
```